# Null Pointer Exception error in StringSpacer method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I made this project for school a year ago and it's a basic text based Pokemon battle arena. I opened it up a couple of days ago to show some friends and I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception error. When i turned it in a year ago it worked perfectly and I haven't made any changes since. I've messed around with both the **displayTeam** methods and **stringSpacer** methods because based upon the error message the problem seems to derive from there.

Here is the error message I get now:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Game.stringSpacer(Game.java:175)
at Game.displayTeam(Game.java:217)
at Game.choosePokemon(Game.java:166)
at PokemonFighter.main(PokemonFighter.java:9)
```

The **stringSpacer** method is used to keep the text in line with the table that displays the stats of your Pokemon team. Here is the **stringSpacer** method:

```
   172   public String stringSpacer(String str, int size){
   173   String before="";
   174   String after="";
   175   size-=str.length();
   176   size/=2;
   177   if(str.length()%2!=0){after+=" ";}
   178   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
   179     before+=" ";
   180     after+=" ";
   181   }
   182   return before+str+after;
   183   }
```

Here is the **displayTeam** method:

```
   212  public void displayTeam(Pokemon[] team){
   213      System.out.println("\n|-NUM-|----POKEMON NAME----|--DEX--|--TYPE 1--|--TYPE 2--|--HP--|-SPEED--|-STATUS-|");
   214      for(int i=0; i<team.length;i++){
   215          String fnt="   OK   ";
   216          if(team[i].checkFaint()){fnt=" FAINT! ";}
   217/218          System.out.println("|  "+i+"  |"+stringSpacer(team[i].getName(),20)+"| "+team[i].getDex()+"  |"+stringSpacer(team[i].getType1(),10)+"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getType2(),10)                     +"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getHp()+"",6)+"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getSpeed()+"",8)+"|"+fnt+"|");
   219      }
   220  }
```

Here is the **choosePokemon** method:

```
   157   public void choosePokemon(){
   158      displayPokemon();
   159      System.out.println("Please Choose 3 Pokemon:");
   160      playerTeam[0] = new Pokemon(input.next());
   161      playerTeam[1] = new Pokemon(input.next());
   162      playerTeam[2] = new Pokemon(input.next());
   163      chooseOpponent();
   164      cleanSpace();
   165      System.out.println("YOUR TEAM:");
   166      displayTeam(playerTeam);
   167      System.out.println("\n\nOPPONENT'S TEAM:");
   168      displayTeam(comTeam);   
   169   }
```

**Pokemon Class Constructor and Data Fields**:

```
     7   private String name, type1, type2, dex, ailment;
     8   private int hp, attack, defense, spAttack, spDefense, speed;
     9   private boolean faint=false;
    10   private int accuracy=100;
    11   private Attack[] moveset;
    12   private Random r = new Random();
    13   
    14   public Pokemon(String id) {
    15     /*
    16      * use Pokedex.txt for pokemon
    17      */
    18     moveset = new Attack[4];
    19     try{
    20         Scanner pokedex = new Scanner(new File("/Final Project/src/PokemonBattle/Pokedex.txt"));
    21        do{       if(pokedex.next().equals(id)){
    22              setDex(id);
    23              setName(pokedex.next());
    24              setType1(pokedex.next());
    25              setType2(pokedex.next());
    26              setHp(pokedex.nextInt());
    27              setAttack(pokedex.nextInt());
    28              setDefense(pokedex.nextInt());
    29              setSpAttack(pokedex.nextInt());
    30              setSpDefense(pokedex.nextInt());
    31              setSpeed(pokedex.nextInt());
    32              setMove(pokedex.next(),0);
    33              setMove(pokedex.next(),1);
    34              setMove(pokedex.next(),2);
    35              setMove(pokedex.next(),3);
    36              break;} 
    37      }while(pokedex.hasNextLine());  
    38      pokedex.close();
    39   }catch(Exception e){}
    40   this.iv();
    41   }
```

**Pokemon setType1 Method**

```
   193   public void setType1(String type1) {
   194      this.type1 = type1;
   195   }
```

**Pokemon setName Method**

```
   185   public void setName(String name) {
   186      this.name = name;
   187   }
```

**Pokemon Text File**:

```
#Pokedex Name, Type1, Type2, HP, Attack, Defense, SpAttack, SpDefense, Speed, Attack 1 2 3 4
#Information from Pokemondb.net
000 Default null null 0 0 0 0 0 0 null null null null
003 Venusaur Grass Poison 80 82 83 100 100 80 Earthquake SludgeBomb EnergyBall DoubleEdge
006 Charizard Fire Flying 78 84 78 109 85 100 Inferno Crunch Slash AirSlash
009 Blastoise Water None 79 83 100 85 105 78 HydroPump Bite IceBeam Earthquake
042 Golbat Poison Flying 75 80 70 65 75 90 AirSlash Bite WingAttack PoisonFang
065 Alakazam Psychic None 55 50 45 135 85 120 GigaImpact Psychic Theif ThunderPunch
068 Machamp Fighting None 90 130 80 65 85 55 DynamicPunch ThunderPunch Earthquake Theif
080 Slowbro Water Psychic 95 75 110 100 80 30 Confusion Earthquake ShadowBall Surf
082 Magneton Electric Steel 50 60 95 120 70 70 ZapCanon GigaImpact FlashCannon Tackle
094 Gengar Ghost Poison 60 65 60 130 75 110 ShadowBall Theif DreamEater ShadowClaw
123 Scyther Bug Flying 70 110 80 55 80 105 XScissor AirSlash SteelWing Theif
124 Jynx Ice Psychic 65 50 35 115 95 95 Blizzard Psychic ShadowBall Pound
143 Snorlax Normal None 160 110 65 65 110 30 Crunch GigaImpact IceBeam Earthquake
```

I want to thank everyone in advance for any input or suggestions you may have for me!

**Edit:** Solution: The text file wasn't being read so the elements in the `Pokemon` arrays were null. Had to go through my classes and change the paths from: `"/PokemonGame/Pokedex.txt"` to `"Pokedex.txt"` and the same for the `Movedex` file. Thanks everyone!

Comment: what variable is the offending variable? Which variable is null?

Comment: You are posting quite a lot of code here for people to wade through. Can you eliminate some irrelevant stuff?

Comment: I assume the variable `str` of method `stringSpacer` is null. That would mean, your pokemon in `team[i]` (method `displayTeam`) is a valid instance, but it stores `null` values for its fields. Can you show us your `Pokemon` class? But maybe not the whole class ... the constructor should be enough.

Comment: You need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Can you show 2 or 3 sample lines of that `Pokedex.txt` file? And check that the if `if(pokedex.next().equals(id))` will be entered at one line. If this doesn't happen, all your fields remain `null` (or `0` or `false`).

Comment: @Tom I posted the `Pokedex.txt` file but are you saying I need to make sure that `if(pokedex.next().equals(id))` starts at the first line of the text file? I tried removing the text on lines one, two and three but the same errors occur.

Comment: No I meant, if you create a new `Pokemon` instance with a specific id, then make sure, that the correct line of your file will be found and evaluated to set the instance fields. For example, if you call `new Pokemon("009")`, then check the the constructor "finds" the line about `Blastoise` correctly.

Comment: And which value do you enter to select your 3 pokemons? Do you also get `InputMismatchException`?

Comment: Oh alright i understand now. I'm new to using the Eclipse Debug tool so I'm not sure how to view whats happening in other classes one step at a time. However, when I do test it I enter 003 006 009. And no I don't get `InputMismatchException`, just the errors listed above.

Comment: It looks like when I create a new `Pokemon` instance with a specific id(003) it isn't finding the correct line. When I inspect it using the Debug mode, it says null.

Comment: Well, then I suggest to avoid pokemon ids like `100` or `105`, because they will cause that exception. And that specific part in the constructor works if I use `003`. If you use a debugger, then step through these lines and see what happens. And please add one or two of these setter methods like `setName` or `setType1` to the question.

Comment: Alright, I think I've figured out the debugger now. I put a breakpoint in line 40 of the `Pokemon` class and ran it. It gets to the `Game` class and after it goes through the `choosePokemon` method each element of the array `playerTeam` is null. So that does confirm that it isn't reading from the file correctly, correct? Also, I added the two setter methods to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the setter method. They are correct. Are the elements of that array null (i.e. does the array look like `[null, null, null]`) or are the variables of these pokemon instances `null`? Your exception "says" the latter. And you said, `after it goes through the choosePokemon method` ... your Exception shows, that it occurs during the `choosePokemon` execution.

Comment: Yeah the `Pokemon` instances are `null`(`playerTeam[0,1,2] = null`).

Comment: Thank you Tom for all your help and everyone else who commented. I just figured it out, and it was something really simple. Instead of putting: `Scanner pokedex = new Scanner(new File("/PokemonGame/Pokedex.txt"));` I put: `Scanner pokedex = new Scaner(new File("Pokedex.txt"));` I learned a lot from all of your suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to decipher your code but its hard with all of the irrelevant code. It is usually best if you give a subset of your code that involves the problem, rather than giving the entire program and asking for us to solve your problem.

With that being said, I've found the problem (well atleast the end of the problem, not the root).

You're passing in null into `stringSpacer`, like this

```
public String stringSpacer(str = null, int size){
    String before="";
    String after="";
    size-=str.length(); 
    size/=2; 
    if(str.length()%2!=0){after+=" ";}
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        before+=" ";
        after+=" ";
    }
    return before+str+after;
}
```

Therefore, when you try to use str as a String, when its actually null, you receive a null pointer exception.

With that being said, this isn't the root of your problem. It seems that when you initialize your `Pokemon[] team`, that some values in the team aren't initialized correctly (they're set to null).

See below for an example of what's going on:

```
public void displayTeam(Pokemon[] team){
    System.out.println("\n|-NUM-|----POKEMON NAME----|--DEX--|--TYPE 1--|--TYPE 2--|--HP--|-SPEED--|-STATUS-|");
    for(int i=0; i<team.length;i++){
        String fnt="   OK   ";
        if(team[i].checkFaint()){fnt=" FAINT! ";}
        System.out.println("|  "+i+"  |"+stringSpacer(null,20)+"|  "+team[i].getDex()+"  |"+stringSpacer(null,10)+"|"+stringSpacer(null,10)
                +"|"+stringSpacer(null +"",6)+"|"+stringSpacer(null +"",8)+"|"+fnt+"|");
    }
}
```

I know not all the values passed into `stringSpacer` are null, but one of them is. Therefore, I think your problem lies in your Pokemon class. Without that code its hard to say though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I shortened up the code quite a bit(sorry about that!), and added the constructor and data fields for the **Pokemon** class. Could the problem be that I didn't import the notepad(.txt) files into Eclipse properly? I imported them as File Systems and their paths are correct in my code. I'm not quite sure, but once again thank you very much! I'll start looking into my Pokemon class more.

Comment: Yup! Use the debugger in eclipse and see if the fields in the Pokemon constructor are actually getting populated. I suspect that your issue is related to reading the file. I have this issue happen sometimes in eclipse. Also, you could try compiling/running separate from any IDE, by using javac sourcecode.java, java sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it:

```
public String stringSpacer(String str, int size){
    if (str == null) return "";
...
```

or fix null value of `team[i].getType1()` or `team[i].getType2()`

also you can just convert them to `"null"` with `+""` :

```
        System.out.println("|  "+i+"  |"+stringSpacer(team[i].getName(),20)+"|  "+team[i].getDex()+"  |"+stringSpacer(team[i].getType1() + "",10)+"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getType2() + "",10)
                +"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getHp()+"",6)+"|"+stringSpacer(team[i].getSpeed()+"",8)+"|"+fnt+"|");
```

Comment: Sure he can avoid it: by fixing his `Pokemon` class. A NPE in that method means, that he has a problem somewhere else.